# How to initialize hidden page objects using appium ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, appium, pageobjects, appium-android

I am using page object model for a mobile app. I am not able to initialize the elements that are hidden on the page but will be visible later in the test. Can someone please suggest what is the solution for it? Following is the code and error:

```
class AppDetails
    include PageObject
    attr_reader :appium_driver, :screen, :button, :header, :more_info, :type
 def initialize(driver, package_name)
    @screen = driver.find_element(blaahh)
    @button = driver.find_element(blaahh)
    @more_info = driver.find_element(blaahh) **###hidden element**
    @type = driver.find_element(blaahh) **###hidden element**
 end
end
```

When I run automation I get following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
    at AndroidDriver.callee$0$0$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-android-driver/lib/commands/find.js:69:13)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-android-driver/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at <anonymous>
```

Thanks,
RV

Comment: Your error says that element doesn't exist. Please include selenium tag when you are using selenium for automation. You are moving out of many people visibility who regularly check questions with selenium tag.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Yes it says element does not exist as it is hidden and will be visible if I click on a show more button.

Comment: No, it wouldn't say element doesn't exist while element is hidden, it would say element is invisible, that means element is coming into existence when you click the button, you better delete this question and repost again because it might have gone down so users of selenium might not have seen.